# How to get values for the next month for a selected column from a pandas data frame with date time index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the below data frame (date time index, with all working days in us calender)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

import random

us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
dt_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='12/31/2018', freq=us_bd)

n1 = [round(random.uniform(20, 35),2) for _ in range(len(dt_rng))]
n2 = [random.randint(100, 200) for _ in range(len(dt_rng))]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(n1,n2)), index=dt_rng, columns=['n1','n2'])

print(df)
```

```
               n1   n2
2018-01-02  24.78  197
2018-01-03  23.33  176
2018-01-04  33.19  128
2018-01-05  32.49  110
...           ...  ...
2018-12-26  31.34  173
2018-12-27  29.72  166
2018-12-28  31.07  104
2018-12-31  33.52  184

[251 rows x 2 columns]
```

For each row in column `n1` , how to get values from the same column for the same day of next month? (if value for that exact day is not available (due to weekends or holidays), then should get the value at the next available date. ). I tried using `df.n1.shift(21)`, but its not working as the exact working days at each month differ.

Expected output as below

```
              n1   n2   next_mnth_val
2018-01-02  25.97  184  28.14
2018-01-03  24.94  133  27.65      # three values below are same, because on Feb 2018, the next working day after 2nd is 5th
2018-01-04  23.99  143  27.65
2018-01-05  24.69  182  27.65
2018-01-08  28.43  186  28.45
2018-01-09  31.47  104  23.14
...           ...  ...    ...
2018-12-26  29.06  194  20.45
2018-12-27  29.63  158  20.45
2018-12-28  30.60  148  20.45
2018-12-31  20.45  121  20.45
```

for December , the next month value should be last value of the data frame ie, value at index `2018-12-31` (20.45).

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I would shift the date by 1 month, then shift it again to the next business day:

```
df1 = df.copy().reset_index()
df1['new_date'] = df1['index'] + pd.DateOffset(months=1) + pd.offsets.BDay()
df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='new_date')
```

Output (first 31st days):

```
      n1_x  n2_x      index   n1_y  n2_y   new_date
0    34.82   180 2018-01-02  29.83   129 2018-02-05
1    34.82   180 2018-01-03  24.28   166 2018-02-05
2    34.82   180 2018-01-04  27.88   110 2018-02-05
3    24.89   186 2018-01-05  25.34   111 2018-02-06
4    31.66   137 2018-01-08  26.28   138 2018-02-09
5    25.30   162 2018-01-09  32.71   139 2018-02-12
6    25.30   162 2018-01-10  34.39   159 2018-02-12
7    25.30   162 2018-01-11  20.89   132 2018-02-12
8    23.44   196 2018-01-12  29.27   167 2018-02-13
12   25.40   153 2018-01-19  28.52   185 2018-02-20
13   31.38   126 2018-01-22  23.49   141 2018-02-23
14   30.90   133 2018-01-23  25.56   145 2018-02-26
15   30.90   133 2018-01-24  23.06   155 2018-02-26
16   30.90   133 2018-01-25  24.95   174 2018-02-26
17   29.39   138 2018-01-26  21.28   157 2018-02-27
18   32.94   173 2018-01-29  20.26   189 2018-03-01
19   32.94   173 2018-01-30  22.41   196 2018-03-01
20   32.94   173 2018-01-31  27.32   149 2018-03-01
21   28.09   119 2018-02-01  31.39   192 2018-03-02
22   32.21   199 2018-02-02  28.22   151 2018-03-05
23   21.78   120 2018-02-05  34.82   180 2018-03-06
24   28.25   127 2018-02-06  24.89   186 2018-03-07
25   22.06   189 2018-02-07  32.85   125 2018-03-08
26   33.78   121 2018-02-08  30.12   102 2018-03-09
27   30.79   137 2018-02-09  31.66   137 2018-03-12
28   29.88   131 2018-02-12  25.30   162 2018-03-13
29   20.02   143 2018-02-13  23.44   196 2018-03-14
30   20.28   188 2018-02-14  20.04   102 2018-03-15
```

Comment: Thank you , is there some way to get value for the dates exactly after one month , for example for index `2018-01-02` new_date should be `2018-02-02`,  for index `2018-01-05 ` , new_date `2018-02-05`  etc,

Comment: you can drop `pd.offsets.BDay()` in the above code.

Comment: @QuangHoang May I ask you to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70426909/235415)?