# pandas computation on rolling 1 calendar month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-computation

I have a pandas DataFrame with date as the index and a column, 'spendings'. I intend to get the rolling max() of the 'spendings' column for the trailing 1 calendar month (not 30 days or 4 weeks).

I tried to capture a snippet with custom data for addressing the problem, below (borrowed from [Pandas monthly rolling operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43556344/235415)):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(
"""\
date          spendings
20210325    15
20210405    20
20210415    10
20210425    40
20210505    3
20210515    2
20210525    2
20210527    1
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(data,sep="\s+", parse_dates=True)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')
del(df['date'])
```

Now, to create a column 'max' to hold rolling last 1 calendar month's max() val, I use:

```
df['max'] = df.loc[(df.index - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)):df.index, 'spendings'].max()
```

This raises an exception like:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-25', '2021-03-05', '2021-03-15', '2021-03-25',
           '2021-04-05', '2021-04-15', '2021-04-25'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)] of type DatetimeIndex
```

However, if I manually access a random month window like below, it works without exception:

```
>>> df['2021-04-16':'2021-05-15']
            spendings
date                 
2021-04-25         40
2021-05-05          3
2021-05-15          2
```

(I could have followed the method using list comprehension here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199274/235415, but I would like to use panda's vectorized method. I have many DataFrames and each is very large - using list comprehension is very slow here).

**Q**: How to get the vectorized method of performing rolling 1 calendar month's max()?

The expected o/p, ie primarily the 'max' column (holding the max value of 'spendings' for last 1 calendar month) will be something like this:

```
>>> df
            spendings  max
date                      
2021-03-25         15   15
2021-04-05         20   20
2021-04-15         10   20
2021-04-25         40   40
2021-05-05         3    40
2021-05-15         2    40
2021-05-25         2    40
2021-05-27         1     3
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the expect result please?

Comment: @Corralien I have added the expected values for 'max' column. If something is unclear, let me know.

Comment: Your question is very clear but I don't how to vectorize the solution.

Comment: Is `df['spendings'].cummax()` enough for you?

Comment: @richardec I need a calendar month - that's a necessity.

Comment: Sure. I though I'd suggest it though be it produced your expected output...but that might just be a coincidence.

Comment: @richardec Actually, I need several calculations on calander month data: max(), count() and there may be some more coming up. My thinking is if I can get the calander month window, I should be able to derive all necessary ones from there on.

Comment: my best try...  I couldn't confirm `transform` is vectorized and I am not satisfied with this solution but hope someone can chime in. 
`df['past_month'] = df.index - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)` `df['min_date'] = df.past_month.transform(lambda x: df.loc[df.index >= x].index[0])` `df['max'] = df.index.to_series().transform(lambda x: df.loc[df.loc[x].min_date:x].spendings.max())`

Comment: @Emma The last statement of your's raise the same exception as I reported. (BTW, you added the 2nd statement to avoid an exception in the process?)

Comment: hmm, if it is the same exception, I am not sure. Because that error is when I try to slice df with index array. That's why I needed to use `transform` to slice with a single value.   2nd statement is because I cannot slice df with non-existing index, so I convert the `past_month` (some are not existing in index) into `min_date` (all existing in the index).

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be

```
[df.loc[x- pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1):x, 'spendings'].max() for x in df.index]

Out[53]: [15, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 3]
```

Comment: I was looking for a vectorized method. This one is list comprehension and consuming much time per dataframe of data (I have ~25K such dataframes)

Comment: @Ethan in your case that is hard ~

Comment: :) Yes, I know. I was aware of the list comprehension method, but ... The problem is with the data types, I presume from the nature of the exception. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong with the data initially (that I documented) - massaging the data in some other way to get this working is probably the way. I am too new with pandas and lost of methods.

Comment: I did some profiling with timeit. For my df, it takes ~1.1 sec and I have ~25K such df-s to process. That's prohibitive!