# replace all occurrences of a set of strings, which appear between two specific words

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python script that will help me replace the logging framework in my c++ application using the re.sub functionality.

The old syntax looks like this:

```
old_log_info("this is an integer: %i, this is a double: %d", 1, 2.0);
old_log_error("this is an integer: %i, this is a double: %d", 1, 2.0);
```

The new syntax:

```
new_log_inf("this is an integer: {}, this is a double: {}", 1, 2.0);
new_log_err("this is an integer: {}, this is a double: {}", 1, 2.0);
```

It has to work on multiline statements as well, that is:

```
old_log_info(
    "this is an integer: %i, this is a double: %d",
    1,
    2.0);
```

Should turn into:

```
new_log_inf(
    "this is an integer: {}, this is a double: {}",
    1,
    2.0);
```

replacing function names is trivial, but replacing format specifiers (`%i`,`%d`, etc.) **only** if appear in the logging expressions is not. the `%i` in:
`printf("this is an integer: %i", 1);` should be untouched.
I have tried playing with lookarounds to isolate the substring between `old_log_info(` and the nearest `);`:

```
re.sub(r'(?s)(?<=old_log_info)(?=\);)', '{}', code)
```

but I can't figure out how to replace only the format specifiers in that match and not the whole match.

Comment: Two questions, what logging function do you use ? And do you know the text of you log lines you are trying to replace ? I guess you example is just an example, not actually what you’re replacing.

Comment: Can you show what you've been playing around with regex wise, otherwise you may not be in the right place.

Comment: It is for a work project, we have are using 2 different in-house frameworks, that we want to replace with thinly wrapped spdlog, but that is really irrelevant - the examples are exhaustive - if you find a "logging function" then replace all format specifiers inside the call with curly braces and do NOTHING else. I've made the new interface such that simply changing the function name and replacing the format specifiers in its arguments will get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two layers of regex. One to find the functions in which to make the changes, and one to actually make the changes.

Below is an example of the logic. Note that it doesn't work if the text in the function contains `);`, in which case it's better to replace the first level of regex by parsing (please provide examples of code if this is the case).

```
code = '''some code %i
old_log_info("this is an integer: %i, this is a double: %d", 1, 2.0);
printf("this is an integer: %i", 1);'''

import re
def repl(m):
    inside = re.sub('%[id]', '{}', m.group(2))
    return f'new_log_info({inside});'

new_code = re.sub('(old_log_info)\((.*?)\);', repl, code)
```

Output:

```
some code %i
new_log_info("this is an integer: {}, this is a double: {}", 1, 2.0);
printf("this is an integer: %i", 1);
```

Comment: This is brilliant in its simplicity and cleverness. Got the job done, thank you :)

Comment: There is one thing missing from the solution - a DOTALL flag either inline: new_code = re.sub('(?s)(old_log_info)\((.*?)\);', repl, code) or as an argument to the call: new_code = re.sub('(old_log_info)\((.*?)\);', repl, code, flags=re.DOTALL). Without this flag multiline expressions won't process correctly.

Comment: @mozway Can you have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70426909/235415)?